# Login redirecting to specific page based on user name

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I'm in the process of learning PHP and MySQL.

I would like from the script to recognize a specific name and redirect it to admin.php. For example "if Username is Brian redirect him to admin.php, if the username is everything except Brian, redirect him to account.php".

Both Brian and the other persons must be registered in the database to be able to login. I thought on redirect based on MySQL user id, but I don't know how to write the code. Or if you know another simple solution.

Here is the script:

```
<?php

 class Users {
     public $username = null;
     public $password = null;
     public $salt = "";

     public function __construct( $data = array() ) {
         if( isset( $data['username'] ) ) $this->username = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['username'] ) );
         if( isset( $data['password'] ) ) $this->password = stripslashes( strip_tags( $data['password'] ) );
     }

     public function storeFormValues( $params ) {
        //store the parameters
        $this->__construct( $params ); 
     }

     public function userLogin() {
         $success = false;
         try{
            $con = new PDO( DB_DSN, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD ); 
            $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            $sql = "SELECT userID FROM users WHERE username='username'  AND password= :password AND userTypeId = 1 LIMIT 1";

        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
            $stmt->bindValue( "username", $this->username, PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->bindValue( "password", hash("sha256", $this->password . $this->salt), PDO::PARAM_STR );
            $stmt->execute();

            $valid = $stmt->fetchColumn();

            if( $valid ) {
                $success = true;
            }

            $con = null;
            return $success;
         }catch (PDOException $e) {
             echo $e->getMessage();
             return $success;
         }
     }
```

And this is the script from index.php (where the user writes his name and password)

```
<?php 
} else {
    $usr = new Users;
    $usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

    if( $usr->userLogin() ) {
        echo "Welcome"; 
    } else {
        echo "Incorrect Username/Password"; 
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: And what is your problem? What should we do to help?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than recognizing a name (which you would have to parse) I believe it would be more efficient (and easier to implement) if you instead direct by user number (or whatever you're calling your primary key).

So if your user name is "Brian" and is the first user, with user number 1 then point to your table where the 1 is located, assuming it's stored as the integer 1 and not the string "1" instead.

Computers generally have an easier time dealing with integers rather than arrays. You can do it by string, but it's always going to be more work for you and the machine.

As far as redirecting goes, upon logging in, just do a check:

`if` user number is equal to [Brian's user number] then redirect to `admin.php`

`else` redirect to `account.php`

(Also you'll want to make sure that `admin.php` requires Brian be the logged in user, or anybody else could just navigate there manually)

Answer (score 0):

The method $user->userLogin should return the id of current login user when successful login and return FALSE when failure login . then redirect to a admin.php or or account.php depend the returned id

Answer (score 0):

First, try to fetch `username` and correct binding name for username:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username = :username AND ...
```

instead of:

```
$sql = "SELECT userID FROM users WHERE username='username' AND ...
             //^                              //^
```

Also just return fetched `username` on successful status. It returns a single column from the next row of a result set or `FALSE` if there are no more rows.

```
return $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

And then check logged in username by `if condition` to redirect desired page:

```
$usr = new Users;
$usr->storeFormValues( $_POST );

$username = $usr->userLogin();
if( $username !== false ) {
    if(strtolower($username) == "brian"){
        header("Location: admin.php");
    } else {
        header("Location: account.php");
    }  
} else {
    echo "Incorrect Username/Password"; 
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it redirects me to account.php no matter who is logging in.

Comment: @AlexOsbourne `var_dump($username);` before `if( $username !== false )`. What do you get?